# ReactJS - Route works but doesn't display the page

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am new to ReactJS, having an issue on viewing the display. The route works, but I need to reload the page to display the content. Is there any possible solution without the user to force reload the page to view the content.

--App.js

```
import React from "react";
import {Route} from "react-router-dom";
import CssBaseline from "@material-ui/core/CssBaseline";
import "./App.css";
import Home from "./components";
import Resume from "./components/Resume"

function App() {
  return (
  <>
    <CssBaseline/> 
    <Route exact path="/" component ={Home}/>
    <Route path="/resume" component ={Resume}/>
  </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

-- Navbar.js

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import MobileRightMenuSlider from '@material-ui/core/Drawer';
import {
    AppBar,
    Toolbar,
    ListItem,
    IconButton,
    ListItemText,
    Avatar,
    Divider,
    List,
    Typography,
    Box,
    ListItemIcon
} from "@material-ui/core"
import {
    ArrowBack,
    AssignmentInd,
    Home,
    Apps,
    ContactMail
} from "@material-ui/icons"
import avatar from "../profile_icon_1.png"

// CSS STYLES
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme=>({
    menuSliderContainer: {
        width: 250,
        background: "black",
        height: "100%"
    },
    avatar: {
        display: "block",
        margin: "0.5rem auto",
        width: theme.spacing(13),
        height: theme.spacing(13)
    },
    listItem: {
        color: "cyan"
    }

}));

// Icons

const menuItems = [
    {
        listIcon: <Home/>,
        listText: "Home",
        listPath: "/"
    },
    {
        listIcon: <AssignmentInd/>,
        listText: "Resume",
        listPath: "/resume"
    },
    {
        listIcon: <Apps/>,
        listText: "Portfolio"
    },
    {
        listIcon: <ContactMail/>,
        listText: "Contacts"
    }
]


const Navbar = () => {
    const [state, setState] = useState({
        right: false
 })

const toggleSlider = (slider, open) => () => {
    setState({...state, [slider]: open});
}

    const classes = useStyles()

    const sideList = slider => (

        <Box className={classes.menuSliderContainer} component="div" onClick={toggleSlider(slider,false)}>
            <Avatar className={classes.avatar} src={avatar} alt="Glenn Java" />
            <Divider/>
            <List>
                {menuItems.map((lsItem, key) => (
                    <ListItem button key={key} component={Link} to={lsItem.listPath}>
                        <ListItemIcon className={classes.listItem}>
                            {lsItem.listIcon}
                        </ListItemIcon>
                        <ListItemText className={classes.listItem} primary={lsItem.listText} />
                    </ListItem>
                ))} 
            </List>
        </Box> 
    )
    return (
        <>
            <Box component="nav">
                <AppBar position ="static" style={{background: "#222"}}>
                    <Toolbar>
                        <IconButton onClick={toggleSlider("right", true)}>
                            <ArrowBack style={{color: "tomato"}}/>                    
                        </IconButton>
                        <Typography variant="h5" style={{color:"tan"}}>Portfolio</Typography>
                        <MobileRightMenuSlider anchor="right" open={state.right} onClose={toggleSlider("right", false)}>
                            {sideList("right")}
                        </MobileRightMenuSlider>
                    </Toolbar>
                </AppBar>
            </Box>
        </>

    )
};

export default Navbar
```

-- Before Reloading
[After clicking the Resume Navbar button, re-directed to this page, but without the content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxALr.jpg)

-- After Reloading
[After reloading the page, the content is now displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AS2st.png)

[Found in Google Chrome Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ej8RH.png)

Comment: you can upload your code to codesanbox or something like that?

Comment: are you using `Router` and `Switch`?

Comment: Hi Joseph, haven't tried using the Switch. Only the router.

Comment: Added the BrowserRouter as Router and Switch.

Answer (score 0):

To make it work, you need to put your `<Route/>` within `Switch` which in turn should be put under `<Router>`

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
} from "react-router-dom";

    <Router>
       <Switch>
           <Route exact path="/" component ={Home}/>
           <Route path="/resume" component ={Resume}/>
        </Switch>
    </Router>
```

Comment: the OP uses `component` Route prop. Please do so.

Comment: Thanks Rahul for the answer, but the issue still occurred.

Comment: Edited the question. Added an issue from the Google Chrome Console.

Comment: Hmm just saw the error. The problem seems to be with the implementation of router as far as I can say from the error

Comment: Can you post the updated code after you made these changes in the answer or preferably can you fork at codesandbox? `<Route path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/resume">
            <Resume />
          </Route>` You may also give this a try once

Comment: Hey Rahul, attached the link here: https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-currying-3lnbq

Comment: Saw the code. The problem is you're defining `switch` and `routes` in the index here. But in your actual application, these links are in different file,i.e, 'navbar.js', hence, producing the errors.